# Why is my network read/write speed so slow on my app?

Tags: c#, client-server, streamreader, streamwriter, fileserver

Ok, so i have made a server\client app for file transportation using a single-thread in a console app. Whenever i run both the client and the server on the same network it runs perfectly, but whenever i try it across the internet it is very, very, slow running at about 130000 bytes a second. The client is using a high-speed ethernet connection and the server is using a wireless connection. I am using port forwarding to send requests for port 54321 to my computer running the server. I am using a `tcplistener` to listen for a connection, a `tcpclient` to accept the connection, a `streamreader` and `streamwriter` attached to a `networkstream` to send/receive data. Any ideas on why it might be so slow? by the way, i know for a fact it is not my wireless network that is causing the lag, i think it is my program. Here is my code :

Server :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool dontloop;
        static string selectedfile;
        static string[] filearray;
        static bool authgood;
        static bool goodexit;
        static string version = "1.0.0";
        static int timeout;
        static bool multifile;
        static bool ipblock;
        static bool auth;
        static string msg;
        static string authpath;
        static string banpath;
        static int port;
        static TcpListener tcp1;
        static TcpClient tcp2;
        static NetworkStream net;
        static StreamReader sr;
        static StreamWriter sw;
        static BinaryReader br;
        static BinaryWriter bw;
        static long length;
        static Int32 buffersize;
        static byte[] buffer;
        static FileStream mainfile;
        static FileStream secondaryfile;
        static string filelength;
        static FileStream settingsfile;
        static StreamReader settingsreader;
        static string path;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.InputEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
                    Console.OutputEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
                    Console.Title = "File Server [Version : " + version + "] <SF>";
                    if (Console.BufferWidth > 59)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(@"
            $$$$$$$$\ $$\ $$\
            $$  _____|\__|$$ |
            $$ |      $$\ $$ | $$$$$$\
            $$$$$\    $$ |$$ |$$  __$$\
            $$  __|   $$ |$$ |$$$$$$$$ |
            $$ |      $$ |$$ |$$   ____|
            $$ |      $$ |$$ |\$$$$$$$\
            \__|      \__|\__| \_______|
 $$$$$$\
$$  __$$\
$$ /  \__| $$$$$$\   $$$$$$\ $$\    $$\  $$$$$$\   $$$$$$\
\$$$$$$\  $$  __$$\ $$  __$$\\$$\  $$  |$$  __$$\ $$  __$$\
 \____$$\ $$$$$$$$ |$$ |  \__|\$$\$$  / $$$$$$$$ |$$ |  \__|
$$\   $$ |$$   ____|$$ |       \$$$  /  $$   ____|$$ |
\$$$$$$  |\$$$$$$$\ $$ |        \$  /   \$$$$$$$\ $$ |
 \______/  \_______|\__|         \_/     \_______|\__|
");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("[FILE SERVER]");
                    }
                    settingsfile = new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString() + @"\settings.cfg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    settingsreader = new StreamReader(settingsfile);
                    string temp0 = settingsreader.ReadToEnd();
                    string[] settings = temp0.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    port = toint(settings.Skip(0).Take(1).First().Split('=').Last());
                    path = settings.Skip(1).Take(1).First().Split('=').Last();
                    authpath = settings.Skip(2).Take(1).First().Split('=').Last();
                    auth = Convert.ToBoolean(settings.Skip(3).Take(1).First().Split('=').Last());
                    banpath = settings.Skip(4).Take(1).First().Split('=').Last();
                    ipblock = Convert.ToBoolean(settings.Skip(5).Take(1).First().Split('=').Last());
                    timeout = toint(settings.Skip(6).Take(1).First().Split('=').Last());
                    multifile = Convert.ToBoolean(settings.Skip(7).Take(1).First().Split('=').Last());
                    settingsfile.Close();
                    settingsreader.Close();
                    tcp1 = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
                    tcp1.Start();
                    Console.WriteLine("Server started. Listening on '{0}'.", tcp1.LocalEndpoint.ToString());
                    tcp2 = tcp1.AcceptTcpClient();
                    tcp1.Server.Close();
                    net = tcp2.GetStream();
                    Console.WriteLine("Client '{0}' connected.", tcp2.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':').First());
                    net.ReadTimeout = timeout;
                    net.WriteTimeout = timeout;
                    Console.WriteLine("Using '{0}' ms timeout.", timeout);
                    sr = new StreamReader(net);
                    sw = new StreamWriter(net);
                    string temp1 = sr.ReadLine();
                    if (temp1 != version)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Client version '" + temp1 + "' does not match server version '" + version + "'!");
                    }
                    sw.WriteLine(net.ReadTimeout.ToString());
                    sw.Flush();
                    if (ipblock == true)
                    {
                        string clientip = tcp2.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':').First();
                        FileStream banstream = File.OpenRead(banpath);
                        StreamReader banreader = new StreamReader(banstream);
                        while (banreader.EndOfStream == false)
                        {
                            if (banreader.ReadLine() == clientip)
                            {
                                throw new Exception("Client IP is banned!");
                            }
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("Client '{0}' is not banned.", clientip);
                    }
                    if (auth == true)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("AUTH=TRUE");
                        sw.Flush();
                        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client response...");
                        string creds = sr.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Client is attempting login as '{0}'.", creds);
                        FileStream authstream = File.OpenRead(authpath);
                        StreamReader authreader = new StreamReader(authstream);
                        while (authreader.EndOfStream == false)
                        {
                            if (authreader.ReadLine() == creds)
                            {
                                authgood = true;
                                sw.WriteLine("ACCEPT");
                                flush();
                                Console.WriteLine("Client login successful.");
                            }
                        }
                        if (authgood == false)
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine("DENY");
                            flush();
                            throw new Exception("Client authentication failed!");
                        }
                    }
                    if (auth == false)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("AUTH=FALSE");
                        sw.Flush();
                    }
                    dontloop = false;
                    while (dontloop == false)
                    {
                        if (multifile == true)
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine("MULTIFILE=TRUE");
                            flush();
                            string temp3 = sr.ReadLine();
                            if (temp3 != "OK")
                            {
                                throw new Exception("Client response was incorrect! errcode=1.");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                while (true)
                                {
                                    filearray = Directory.GetFiles(path);
                                    foreach (string s in filearray)
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            secondaryfile = File.OpenRead(s);
                                            filelength = secondaryfile.Length.ToString();
                                            secondaryfile.Close();
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception)
                                        {
                                            filelength = "(length unavailable)";
                                        }
                                        sw.WriteLine("{0} | {1} bytes.", s, filelength);
                                        sw.Flush();
                                    }

                                    sw.WriteLine("STATUS=DONE");
                                    sw.Flush();
                                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client response...");
                                    selectedfile = sr.ReadLine();
                                    Console.WriteLine("Received client response.");
                                    if (selectedfile != "0")
                                    {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("Client refreshed file list.");
                                    }
                                }
                                int index = Convert.ToInt32(selectedfile) - 1;
                                string temp5 = filearray.Skip(index).Take(1).ToArray().First().ToString();
                                Console.WriteLine("Client selected '{0}'.", temp5);
                                mainfile = File.OpenRead(temp5);
                                length = mainfile.Length;
                                if (length < 65000)
                                {
                                    buffersize = toint(length.ToString());
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    buffersize = 65000;
                                }
                                Console.WriteLine("Using '{0}' byte buffer.", buffersize.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                        if (multifile == false)
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine("MULTIFILE=FALSE");
                            flush();
                            string temp3 = sr.ReadLine();
                            if (temp3 != "OK")
                            {
                                throw new Exception("Client response was incorrect! errcode=2.");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    secondaryfile = File.OpenRead(path);
                                    filelength = secondaryfile.Length.ToString();
                                    secondaryfile.Close();
                                }
                                catch (Exception)
                                {
                                    filelength = "(length unavailable)";
                                }
                                sw.WriteLine("{0} | {1}", path, filelength);
                                sw.Flush();
                                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client response...");
                                string temp4 = sr.ReadLine();
                                Console.WriteLine("Received client response.");
                                if (temp4 != "OK")
                                {
                                    throw new Exception("Client response was incorrect! errcode=3.");
                                }
                                mainfile = File.OpenRead(path);
                                length = mainfile.Length;
                                if (length < 65000)
                                {
                                    buffersize = toint(length.ToString());
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    buffersize = 65000;
                                }
                                Console.WriteLine("Using '{0}' byte buffer.", buffersize.ToString());
                            }

                        }
                        sw.WriteLine(mainfile.Length.ToString());
                        sw.Flush();
                        sw.WriteLine("READY?");
                        sw.Flush();
                        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client response...");
                        string temp6 = sr.ReadLine();
                        if (temp6 != "YES")
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Client response was incorrect! errcode=4.");
                        }
                        br = new BinaryReader(mainfile);
                        bw = new BinaryWriter(net);
                        while (true)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                string temp9 = sr.ReadLine();
                                if (temp9.ToString() == "DONE")
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine();
                                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client response...");
                                    string temp7 = sr.ReadLine();
                                    if (temp7 == "CLOSE")
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            tcp2.Close();
                                            if (tcp2.Connected == false)
                                            {
                                                throw new Exception();
                                            }
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception)
                                        {
                                            goodexit = true;
                                            dontloop = true;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (temp7 == "AGAIN")
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("Client wants to download another file.");
                                        mainfile.Close();
                                        dontloop = false;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                long temp8 = Convert.ToInt64(temp9);
                                mainfile.Position = temp8;
                                if (length - temp8 >= buffersize)
                                {
                                    buffersize = 65000;
                                }
                                if (length - temp8 < buffersize)
                                {
                                    buffersize = toint((length - temp8).ToString());
                                }
                                buffer = new byte[buffersize];
                                buffer = br.ReadBytes(buffer.Length);
                                bw.Write(buffer);
                                string percent = Math.Round(((double)((double)temp8 / (double)length) * 100), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();
                                if (percent == "100" && temp8 < length) { percent = "<100"; }
                                Console.Write("\rClient requested {0} / {1} bytes | {2}% done.   ", temp8, length, percent);
                                bw.Flush();
                            }
                            catch (Exception err)
                            {
                                dontloop = true;
                                goodexit = false;
                                closeall();
                                Console.WriteLine();
                                Console.WriteLine(err.Message.ToString());
                                Console.WriteLine();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (goodexit == true)
                        {
                            closeall();
                            Console.WriteLine("Task complete.");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    closeall();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(err.Message.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Server restarting in 10 seconds.");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        }
        static int toint(string string_)
        {
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(string_);
            return i;
        }
        static void halfclose()
        {
            mainfile.Close();
            bw.Close();
            br.Close();
        }
        static void flush()
        {
            sw.Flush();
        }
        static void closeall()
        {
            try
            {
                br.Close();
            }
            catch { }
            try
            {
                bw.Close();
            }
            catch { }
            try
            {
                sr.Close();
            }
            catch { }
            try
            {
                sw.Close();
            }
            catch { }
            try
            {
                net.Close();
            }
            catch { }
            try
            {
                tcp2.Close();
            }
            catch { }
            try
            {
                tcp1.Server.Close();
            }
            catch { }
            try
            {
                tcp1.Stop();
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
}
```

Client : can be found here -> `ftp://98.122.51.199/Program.cs`
(too many characters for body, address above is my FTP server)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to flush the stream.  I do however believe your delays are from harddisk io.

Comment: flushing the stream is required to write bytes to the stream using the `streamwriter.writeline()` and `binarywriter.write()`.